# Result is not properly displaying using Stack Exchange Data Explorer Queries?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I checked the top 50 users of a particular city using a query in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

You can see the result [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/419442/top-50-users-from-rajkot), and I am not able to find my name in the list, while my city name is the same.

Is there a problem with data updates?

Comment: The data explorer is not live data - it gets updated weekly. When did you update your location?

Comment: before 2 days i updated

Comment: That would do it. Wait for after the weekend.

Comment: i think you are right when i run with my previous city it shows my name..http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/420339

Comment: @Sha - I don't know the exact schedule - in this case, likely that the update happened before the OP changed their location field.